# How make a chatbot with Watson Conversation and Slack?

Tags: chat, integration, chatbot, slack-api, watson-conversation

I want to build a Slack bot that can answer support queries. I've designed the conversation in Watson Conversation, but now I want to deploy it to Slack channels.

Ideally I don't want to have to develop and host an application to broker messages between the two systems.

Is there any platform or solution that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions that I can think of.

Watson Conversation offers some basic integration with Slack through an application you can deploy yourself in a container. I believe they have a repo in their github (https://github.com/IBM/slack-watson-bot). You'll have to host this somewhere, though Bluemix offers some basic free hosting for a limited time. There are plenty of tutorials out there for spinning up containers in Bluemix.

An alternative solution (disclosure - this is my company) that wouldn't require hosting or development would be to use Bothaus (https://bothaus.io). Bothaus lets you configure integration between Slack and Watson Conversation without hosting or coding anything.

Comment: You can deploy directly to Slack now in Conversation.

Answer (score 1):

In Watson Conversation while in your conversation workspace, click on the Deploy icon.

[image]

After that, click deploy on the Slack card. Click "Deploy to Slack App", and follow the steps.

You should not need to code anything, just fill related fields with data.

---

Just be aware, if your URLs you are requested to enter into slack contain spaces, change them to `%20` so that Slack will recognise the URL.